# wsl cannot access ubuntu path from command line

Tags: ubuntu, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

e.g. I have gcc in path (ubuntu) but when I use

```
wsl gcc
```

I get `/bin/bash: gcc: command not found`

by running this command I only see windows paths not ubuntu:

```
#powershell
wsl echo `$PATH
```

what should I do to access ubuntu executables in path using just wsl command line??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `gcc` is in your WSL/Ubuntu path, but not showing up when you try to execute it via `wsl gcc`, then that's likely a manifestation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66048183/11810933).  When executed with a command, WSL launches the shell as a non-login, non-interactive shell.

If you've modified the path inside `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or any related file (depending on your shell), then you need to tell WSL to launch your shell with the proper flags to read those config files.  Try:

```
wsl -e bash -lic "gcc"
```

- `-l` for login shell
- `-i` for interactive shell
- `-c` to specify the command

Comment: thank you so much!